# QGIS Plugin to auto-fill attributes from prepared list on feature creation

Tags: qgis-plugins, editing, features

Is there a QGIS Plugin that does some or all of the following:

On feature creation in editing mode:

- offer a drop down list of rows of attributes,
- let the user select one of the offered items
- accordingly auto-fill the attributes of the newly created feature.

I already searched the QGIS plugin  repository, didnt find anything likely

Comment: It seem that configuring attribute form, maybe using default value and some expression would get you close to that, read this https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/forms.html#ls-forms and maybe update your question to request clarification